# Same date is repeating on my custom 'Most Recent Posts' on sidebar

Tags: sidebar, date

If you look at the 'most recent posts' on my sidebar for my posts page, you can see that the 'date' is repeating. The code and page is below. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

https://cenbrandlab.org/home-blog/

```
<!-- [SINGLEPOST SIDEBAR MOST POPULAR ARTICLES] [START]-->
<div class="c-singlepost__sidebar__articles">
    <h3 class="c-singlepost__sidebar__articles-title"><?php the_field("side_post_list_title", "option"); ?></h3>

    <?php

    $args = [
            "numberposts" => 5
    ];
     $recent_posts = get_posts($args);

//         echo "<pre>";
//         echo var_dump($recent_posts);
//         echo "</pre>";

     foreach ($recent_posts as $value):

    ?>

     <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($value->ID); ?>">
        <div class="c-singlepost__sidebar__articles-item">
            <div class="c-singlepost__sidebar__articles-item-image">
                <img src="<?php echo get_field("thumbnail_image",$value->ID); ?>"  class="responsive-image"/>

            </div>
            <div class="c-singlepost__sidebar__articles-item-right">
                <div class="c-singlepost__sidebar__articles-item-date">
                    <span>  <?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y'); ?> </span>
                </div>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($value->ID); ?>" class="c-singlepost__sidebar__articles-item-post">
                    <?php echo $value->post_title ?>
                </a>

            </div>
        </div>
     </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The same date is always displayed because of the use of `echo get_the_date('F j, Y')`.
As you can read in the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date):

> The **get_the_date** template tag retrieves the date the **current** $post was written.

Change `get_the_date('F j, Y')` to `get_the_date('F j, Y', $value->ID)` and it should work.

Or without additional DB queries:

```
<div class="c-singlepost__sidebar__articles-item-date">
    <span>  <?php 
         $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value->post_date);
         echo ($date !== FALSE) ? $date->format('F j, Y') : ''; 
    ?> </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
  <span>  <?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y'); ?> </span>
```

with

```
  <span>  <?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y', $value->ID); ?> </span>
```